# How can I run MongoDB server and visual studio unit tests in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: .net, docker, azure-devops

I have a set of Visual Studio unit test projects which uses mongodb for execution.

I want to run the tests using Azure DevOps pipeline, can anyone help me with the YAML snippet for the same? (I am new to Azure pipelines and docker)

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out below answer? How did it work with you?

Answer (score 1):

In future it would help if you posted your current YAML pipeline for additional context or possible gotchas.

But here is a rough pipeline using a [service container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers);

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: mongodb
    image: mongodb
    ports:
    - 27017:27017

services:
  mongodb: mongodb

steps:

#insert pre-test set-up steps here

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: **/*.Tests/*.csproj
    arguments: --configuration Release
```

Your integration tests should use a host value of 'mongodb:27017' in the connection string.